# How to get a list of files and its copies from a directory that matches a file name

Tags: java, regex, list, file

I have a directory with the list of files below.

- test
- test(1)
- test(2)
- test_x.log
- test_x(1).log

In the above list test(1) and test(2) are copies of original test file.

I want a get a list of files(and its copies) by providing the file name.

For example:
-Input: test
-Output List should contain:
--test
--test(1)
--test(2)

The list should not contain test_x.log or its copies. Based on the list I should find the last iteration of the file copy and create a new file copy like test(3) from the original test file.

The below code also gives the test_x.log. Tried with contains and some regex patterns. Did not work out.

```
String filePath = "C:\\TestFolder";
String finalFileName = "test";

List<File> files = Files.list(Paths.get(filePath))
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().startsWith(finalFileName))
        .sorted()
        .map(Path::toFile)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: A filename usually has an extension. For your purposes are we to assume no extensions? If so then `path.getFileName().toString().matches('test(?:\(\d+\))?')` should do it. See https://regex101.com/r/PFwLCI/1/ and note that the `.matches()` method adds the start and end line anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Used Regex:

```
"test(?:\\(\\d+\\))?(?:\\.|$)"
```

Regex in context and testbench:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "C:\\TestFolder";
    String finalFileName = "test";

    //Regex for matching:
    // C:\TestFolder\test(1).txt || C:\TestFolder\test(2).txt || C:\TestFolder\test.txt
    // and C:\TestFolder\test(1) || C:\TestFolder\test(2) || C:\TestFolder\test
    // regex : "test(?:\\(\\d+\\))?(?:\\.|$)"
    String regex =  String.format("%s(?:\\(\\d+\\))?(?:\\.|$)", finalFileName);
    Pattern extractFilePattern = Pattern.compile(regex); // Pre-compile before loop

    List<File> extractedFiles = Files.list(Paths.get(filePath))
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .filter(path -> extractFilePattern.matcher(path.getFileName().toString()).find())
    .map(Path::toFile)
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //Output:
    extractedFiles.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
C:\TestFolder\test(1)
C:\TestFolder\test(2)
C:\TestFolder\test
```

Files in file system:

```
C:\TestFolder\test(1)
C:\TestFolder\test(2)
C:\TestFolder\test
C:\TestFolder\test_x(1).log
C:\TestFolder\test_x.log
C:\TestFolder\test_x.log
```